# Delete orphans when deleting parent manyToOne annotaion

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two entities, related as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPOINTMENT")
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long codeAp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
,   @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codeP")
    private Patient patient;

    //attributes
    //getters and setters
    //constructors



@Entity
@Table(name = "PATIENT")
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long codeP;

    //attributes
    //getters and setters
    //constructors
```

I'm using JpaRepository delete method.
There is a constraint between the tables PATIENT and APPOINTMENT in database,
I want to remove orphans, when I remove Patient.
I added @OnDelete hibernate annotation but it doesn't work for me!
Can you please tell me why? 
I want to keep that unidirectional relationship, can you please help me in this?

Comment: Have you tried `orphanRemoval` flag?

Comment: but orphanRemoval goes with OneToMay relationship , in my case I'm using ManyToOne relationship

Comment: `ManyToOne` is a synthetic relation, in the database the relation is modeled using only the `OneToMany` relation. If you want to remove Appointments when the Patient is deleted, then you should cascade the delete operation, as you do. OrphanRemoval means that JPA will keep track of which Appointments are in the syntic `ManyToOne` collection, and if you remove an Appointment from a Patient's collection, JPA will delete it when the transaction commits. This has a (small) cost since JPA has to keep track of which Appointments are there when Patient is loaded, and do a diff during commit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep using the association as unidirectional only, you can define the lazy-loaded inverse side in a field without exposing getters and setters for it:

```
@Entity
public class Patient {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Appointment> appointments;
}
```

This way `orphanRemoval` logic is applied from patients to their appointments and as a bonus you get the ability to navigate from patients to appointments in HQL queries.

Notice the `mappedBy` attribute which tells that appointments are responsible for the association management, so you continue to associate appointments with patients by setting patients in the many-to-one relation defined in the `Appointment`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that you could achieve that automatic behavior on the `@ManyToOne` side. Its just semantically incorrect, period.

Taking under consideration though, the fact that you only want to have an uni-directional mapping and do not specify the `Set<Appointment>` dependency on the `Patient`, then a kind of workaround to your situation would be to replace the `@ManyToOne` with a `@OneToOne` relationship. Then you would be able to use `orphan-removal` functionality:

```
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codeP")
    private Patient patient;
```

Keep in mind though that if you follow this path, adapt you code and at some point you will be in need to introduce `@OneToMany` dependency on the `Patient' side then you will stumble upon problems. So i would recommend working out pros and cons first in relation to future possible alteration to the entity graph.

Comment: Thank you, I'm about changing mapping to OneToMany relationship

Comment: @OneToOne if you want to follow my idea ;)

Comment: I'm about changing the nature of the relationship to bi-directionnal

Comment: in case of bi-directionnal, can I just insert from ManyToOne side, not from OneToMany side?

Comment: Yes, you would have, because only `@OneToMany` and `@OneToOne` have that feature